# Template suggestions periodically not being recognized

Tags: 7, theming, theme-negotiation

I have some simple template suggestions setup in my `THEME_preprocess_node()` function. Example:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'MY_TYPE' && $vars['view_mode'] == 'MY_VIEW_MODE') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'my__template';
  }
}
```

Then I have the template file (named `my--template.tpl.php`) setup in my theme. I cleared the cache, and this is recognized right away and works fine.

Then, after about an hour, if I refresh the page that uses the template, it suddenly is not recognized anymore. I clear cache again and it comes back.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Just FYI, I am using `hook_theme()` in a custom module to specify the theme for this page based on the URL alias.

Comment: Do you maybe use themekey, admin_theme or some other theme handler module?

Comment: @leymannx No, it's a custom module only handling theme switching. However, I think I have found the issue. I specified the wrong hook name! I had other_theme_preprocess_node instead of my_theme_preprocess_node. I copied the hook from another theme and forgot to change the base. What a rookie move.

Comment: Just going to wait another hour or so to make sure that was it. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @leymannx Seems to have done the trick. Thanks again for jumping in.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the wrong hook specified. I copied this from another theme and forgot to update the hook prefix. So I had:

```
other_theme_preprocess_node
```

instead of:

```
my_theme_preprocess_node
```

Changing that seems to have resolved the issue.